# Is it possible to store plain text in flot jquery datasets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

please take a quick look at this sample script (it wont work in iexplorer)

http://jsfiddle.net/VpGnS/10/

Now take a look at where the coordinates are printed out on that page under the graph. Is it possible that instead of printing out plain integers, write out another dataset that is containing a string in that place??

Like for example say that I do something like this, I add

```
 "COSTestNames": {
        label: "Testnames",
        data: [[1, "test1-a1"], [2,  "test1-a2" ], [3, "test1-a3"], [4,  "test1-a4" ]]}
```

&

```
"CASTestNames": {
    label: "Testnames",
    data: [[1, "test2-a1"], [2,  "test2-a2" ], [3, "test2-a3"], [4,  "test2-a4" ]]}
```

&

```
"MVETestNames": {
    label: "Testnames",
    data: [[1, "test3-a1"], [2,  "test3-a2" ], [3, "test3-a3"], [4,  "test3-a4" ]]}
```

etc... to datasets[0], datasets[ 1] & datasets[2]

And when I hover a certain X interval I am in, say I am in the intervall 1-2 in the X cordinates, I then want it to print out, if MVETest3failed is displayed on the graph, then print out "test3-a2". When I'm finished it won't be able to show objects from both MVE,COS and CAS, so don't bother that scenario =)

Or if its not possible to do like this, is there any other way to accomplish this in a similar way? =)

Comment: Do you mean something like [this example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html)? (You will need to click the 'Enable Tooltip' checkbox)

Comment: Yes, but instead of shoving the label from "cover" or "failed" (in that example it shows the string sin or cos) it shall show from MVETestNames, CASTestNames etc, "test3-a1", if the cursor is in the intervall 0-1, and "test3-a2" if the cursor x value is between 1-2 (dvs x 1<x<2) and "test3-a3" if x is between 2 & 3 (2<x<3) etc =)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/VpGnS/47/

This does as you would like.

I modified the `mouseActiveRadius` property of the grid and modified your `plothover` function.

Up vote if this is what you wanted. I know it's been several weeks since you asked, but I figured I would send out an answer, anyway.